# better cpp vector insert(initial) writing

Tags: c++, vector

i am trying to initial a vector of a defined class in another instance, the test code is as:

```cpp
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    float x = 0.0;
};

class B
{
public:
    std::vector<A> b;
};

int main()
{
    B x;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        A y;
        x.b.insert(x.b.begin(), y);
    }
       
}
```

but is there a more brilliant writing for the initial of `x`?
something maybe like

`x.b.insert(x.b.begin(), 3, A);`
which i got error `error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token`
thx

edit: sorry, edited for a better example

Comment: `std::vector<A> a(3);` ... or `std::vector<A> a; a.resize(3);`

Comment: It is not clear what you actually need. If you need to initialize `a` with 3 elements of default constructed `A` - @ChrisMM commented how to do it.

Comment: sorry, the original post is a bad and wrong example, already updated

Comment: fwiw, "brillant" or "clever" code is not something desriable. Good code is clean and readable and boring

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop or `insert`, just construct the vector and assign it

```
B.x = std::vector<A>(3);
```

or if you have a particular value in mind

```
A y = something;
B.x = std::vector<A>(3, y);
```

Maybe this code should be in the constructor for `B`.

Comment: thx, `x.b = std::vector<A>(3);`  maybe nice, but i just found `B` is a more compilcated construction that cannot be assigned like this...B is wrote by another guy...maybe just `for` loop...

Comment: @furynerd If you can write `x.b.insert(...)` then you can write `x.b = ...;`. If `x.b` is a vector then it can be inserted to or assigned to, there's no difference.